# Which gcc is being used on Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: unix, gcc, ubuntu, compiler-construction, x86

I installed the latest version of `gcc` on my `linux-x86` from the command line. The `/usr/bin/` shows two `gcc`s, namely `gcc` and `gcc-4.4`. After browsing a few sites, I navigated to my `/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu`. It contains a folder `4.4/` and two other files, `4.4.4` as well as `4.4.5`.

When I use `gcc -v`, I get

> gcc version 4.4.5 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.4.4-14ubuntu5.1)

`whereis gcc` shows

> gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc

which gcc shows `/usr/bin/gcc`.

What is the difference between the two gccs I found in my `/usr/bin/`? Which one is the system picking up?

What is the difference between the outputs of whereis gcc and which gcc?

I believe if I understand these, I'll be able to debug the errors in my build.

Comment: this is so trivial...you can just google it instead

Comment: I only see one, which is "gcc". It's probably a symlink (maintained by `dpkg` / `update-alternatives`) to a specific version, but you only have one specific version, called gcc-4.4 (not gcc; gcc-4.4). Some developers need a specific version and/or multiple different versions of gcc, which is when this arrangement becomes useful, but you should be able to simply ignore it. Certainly you should trust the output from `gcc -v`.

Answer (score 0):

The binary in "/usr/bin/gcc" is probably just an alias. Since "which gcc" points to that one, follow that alias to find your default system gcc, which if I had to guess, was set to the gcc "4.4.5". What is in the 4.4/ folder?

Also, my guess is that gcc-4.4 is yet another alias, probably to the 4.4.4 or a bin in the 4.4/ folder. These are just guesses, so my first step at solving this is to follow them and see where they point.

Answer (score 0):

I think the system picks up the version which replies to `gcc -v`.
Maybe you've installed more than one GCC version? Or you've compiled a software which needed using a specific GCC version? That could be because some building configurations refer to a specific GCC name version or use directives specifics of a GCC version, just like some Java software do with the Java Virtual Machine. Java softwares often install their JVM unregarding the fact that you've one installed yet.

From http://www.linfo.org/whereis.html:

The whereis command is used to locate the binary, the source code and the online manual page for any specified program.

From http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_which.htm:

which - shows the full path of (shell) commands (so the executables).

Answer (score 0):

yes it will definitely show two gcc's. What you have to do is that after installation of gcc through commandline youhave to link it. For example for c first you have to remove cc1 and then link new cc1 with absolute path. For more reference go through this link 
http://buildall.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/installing-gcc-4-6-in-the-ubuntu-10-10/